# How to pass form input properties from a dynamic form into a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with dynamically added rows that need to have different properties for dynamic use, submit, etc. How can I pass their properties without a fixed `name`, `id` or `class`?

The dynamically created element:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input1" onkeyup="foo(this.name, this.value);"/>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
foo(this.name, this.value){
    //data handler
};
```

I can´t rely on static properties for the function, they have to be passed after the element is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you tried using **foo(this)**?

And in function, gets properties.

```
function foo(node) {
    node.property;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener after the object is created by using:

```
your_new_object.addEventListener('keyup',foo,false);
```

Comment: This solution isn't cross-browser (not working in IE8 or lower), and the second parameter must be "foo", not "foo()".